# AWS SWF Generate Sources Activity Clients

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-swf

I am following an example on amazon aws site for swf workflows.  I am trying to get my aws swf activities to generate their clients. I am using Intellij Ultimate with Maven. I have seen some things online about AspectJ and interweaving code?!?.

Example Activity

```
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Activities;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.ActivityRegistrationOptions;

@ActivityRegistrationOptions(defaultTaskScheduleToStartTimeoutSeconds = 300,
        defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 10)
@Activities(version = "1.0")
public interface GreeterActivities {
    public String getName();

    public String getGreeting(String name);

    public void say(String what);
}
```

Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>play3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <jackson.version>2.7.2</jackson.version>
        <jersey.version>2.22.2</jersey.version>
        <jaxrs.api.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.api.version>
        <aws.version>1.10.58</aws.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxrs.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-autoscaling</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudformation</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ is used only for @Asynchronous and @ExponentialRetry annotations. It is not used for code generation. The Java annotation processor (found in aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools) performs this task. It is hard to guess the problem looking at your pom file. Would you look at the working pom from https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=760211&#760211 to see if there is something missing in yours?